# Is the following step in a Red and Black Tree correct? Did I skip or miss something?

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

Doing the following step in  Red and Black tree. I am not sure if I rotated correctly.

[image: handdrawn image of a red black tree]

Comment: It should be done after the first step.  Leve 20 black and 14, 23 red.

Comment: The rule for insert is: 3 red children => recolor and fix the parent.  2 red children => rotate if necessary to redistribute the children and you're done.  You should never be propagating a red after rotating.